UC3844 IC duty cycle problem
Recently I started building a flyback converter with a targeted input voltage of 12-24 V and output voltage of 150 V. The swicthing frequency is set to 100 kHz, for testing purposes I've used a voltage divider with a variable preset for setting the feedback voltage.
The issue is the output duty cycle of the UC3844 IC always jumps to 46% when the feedback voltage is above 2.5 Vref and goes to 0% when feedback voltage is below 2.5 Vref. There seems to be no varying between duty cycle of the output, it just jumps straight to max duty cycle. I've never seen this sort of problem before.
Here is the circuit,sorry for bad drawing.

Thanks in advance, this may be elementary question but you're answer will be very helpfull. If more information is needed I will provide soon as possible in the comment section.
Edit:here is the completed circuit diagram

Primary = 5 turns litz wire
Secondary = 65 turns 0.32mm enameled copper
Core spec unknown.

When you close the loop then  update your              post ,it may not be a problem.

Please post a complete schematic. Click on edit and then on the schematic symbol. You can draw it there. I don’t see any feedback loop. Include transformer specs.

The UC384x is a current-mode controller and expects some signal on the CS pin. Since you have grounded it, the only available PWM reset information is the maximum duty ratio limit. To operate the controller in voltage-mode control, and observe a variable duty ratio without resorting to a current sense information, you have to cheat the controller and bring a ramp to the CS pin. Look at slide 137 of my APEC 2019 seminar to see how to build this ramp. It could also be done by a simple RC between DRV and CS pin.

@VerbalKint thanks for the information,i didn't know the current sensing pin of the ic will have an effect on this. As mentioned above i will close the loop and update soon as possible,and also with a completed latest schematic.

@Autistic,I will close the loop of the circuit and update soon as possible

@winny, the Transformer used is custom wounded for my application,honestly i dont have much info about the core material,because it was salvage from a swicthing power supply.Also i will update with a completed and latest schematic soon as possible

If it's custom wound, you must know which spec it's wound to.

@winny, the core spec is unknown but the primary is 5 turns,secondary is 65 turns,after building the full circuit i was able to obtain maximum 357vdc with a 5w resistive load attached.

If you are developing a flyback converter, you need to know the magnetizing inductance as it is a design parameter. Anyhow, not the issue at hand, it will just come later.

@winny thanks for making it clear,i will study about the topic,Is  there a way to obtain core permeability value with oscilloscope and function gen ?

Yes. Do a search, it's covered many times. Or buy a cheap LCR meter. I use Agilent U1733C.

@winny,aight thank you for teaching and providing info,helps alot man.

The UC384x controller is a current-mode controller and needs a reset through it current-sense (CS) pin. If no current information is detected, the controller goes to maximum duty ratio. One way to cheat the controller, for experimental purposes, is to buffer the oscillator ramp and inject the scaled-down value to the CS pin:

By adjusting the voltage on the CMP pin, you will change the current-sense setpoint and operate the circuit in voltage-mode control, exactly as I did on slide 137 of my APEC 2019 seminar. In the SIMPLIS simulation, the duty ratio increases from a few percents up to its maximum value, 95%. Please note that the internal setpoint is the CMP level minus two diode drops, further divided by 3.

,thank you very much,after closing the loop i was able to get the circuit working as i wanted,and also thanks for making clear about the isense pin on the uc3844 ic.

With pleasure! In your circuit, make sure the 100-pF/1-kOhms components are very closely located to the UC384x for the best noise immunity. Same for the other small components around the circuit, their ground should return to the IC GND pin, like the 8.2-kOhms in the feedback network for instance. Good luck with these experiments.
